# Como abrir o vlc com o flask no rapberry py

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, libvlc

alguém já tentou iniciar o vlc através do Flask? Estou tentando através de API com Flask iniciar uma reprodução de video no vlc, ele executa mas não iniciar a interface gráfica. Alguém já passou por algo semelhante?